# How can I figure out which framework was used for build desktop application's (Zoom) UI?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, reverse-engineering

I would like to know which framework was used to build Zoom(windows & mac)'s UI.

Is that possible somehow? Would decompiling help?

[Zoom's desktop application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98lzs.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [Zoom's Linux client](https://zoom.us/download?os=linux) and choose *Other Linux OS* from the drop down menu. Then run the following command in a Linux terminal:

```
$ tar -xf zoom_x86_64.tar.xz
```

The execution of the command results in a directory called `zoom` being created and when you list it's contents using this command:

```
$ ls zoom
```

You get the following output:

```
audio                  libQt5DBus.so.5                 libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5.12.9  libturbojpeg.so
dingdong1.pcm          libQt5DBus.so.5.12              libQt5QuickWidgets.so            meeting_chat_chime.pcm
dingdong.pcm           libQt5DBus.so.5.12.9            libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5          meeting_raisehand_chime.pcm
double_beep.pcm        libQt5Gui.so                    libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.12       platforminputcontexts
Droplet.pcm            libQt5Gui.so.5                  libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.12.9     platforms
egldeviceintegrations  libQt5Gui.so.5.12               libQt5Script.so                  platformthemes
Embedded.properties    libQt5Gui.so.5.12.9             libQt5Script.so.5                Qt
generic                libQt5Network.so                libQt5Script.so.5.12             qt.conf
getbssid.sh            libQt5Network.so.5              libQt5Script.so.5.12.9           QtGraphicalEffects
getmem.sh              libQt5Network.so.5.12           libQt5Svg.so                     QtQml
iconengines            libQt5Network.so.5.12.9         libQt5Svg.so.5                   QtQuick
imageformats           libQt5OpenGL.so                 libQt5Svg.so.5.12                QtQuick.2
json                   libQt5OpenGL.so.5               libQt5Svg.so.5.12.9              QtWayland
leave.pcm              libQt5OpenGL.so.5.12            libQt5WaylandClient.so           record_start.pcm
libfdkaac2.so          libQt5OpenGL.so.5.12.9          libQt5WaylandClient.so.5         record_stop.pcm
libicudata.so          libQt5Qml.so                    libQt5WaylandClient.so.5.12      ring.pcm
libicudata.so.56       libQt5Qml.so.5                  libQt5WaylandClient.so.5.12.9    ringtone
libicudata.so.56.1     libQt5Qml.so.5.12               libQt5Widgets.so                 sip
libicui18n.so          libQt5Qml.so.5.12.9             libQt5Widgets.so.5               timezones
libicui18n.so.56       libQt5QuickControls2.so         libQt5Widgets.so.5.12            translations
libicui18n.so.56.1     libQt5QuickControls2.so.5       libQt5Widgets.so.5.12.9          version.txt
libicuuc.so            libQt5QuickControls2.so.5.12    libQt5X11Extras.so               wayland-decoration-client
libicuuc.so.56         libQt5QuickControls2.so.5.12.9  libQt5X11Extras.so.5             wayland-graphics-integration-client
libicuuc.so.56.1       libQt5Quick.so                  libQt5X11Extras.so.5.12          wayland-graphics-integration-server
libmpg123.so           libQt5Quick.so.5                libQt5X11Extras.so.5.12.9        wayland-shell-integration
libQt5Core.so          libQt5Quick.so.5.12             libQt5XcbQpa.so                  wr_ding.pcm
libQt5Core.so.5        libQt5Quick.so.5.12.9           libQt5XcbQpa.so.5                xcbglintegrations
libQt5Core.so.5.12     libQt5QuickTemplates2.so        libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.12             zoom
libQt5Core.so.5.12.9   libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5      libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.12.9           ZoomLauncher
libQt5DBus.so          libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5.12   libquazip.so                     zopen
```

As you can see, a lot of the filenames start with `libQt5` or `Qt`, so I would assume, that the framework used to develop the Linux desktop client is the [Qt Framework](https://www.qt.io/product/framework). And because the Linux client and the Windows client share the same user interface, they are probably both using Qt.